# IOS 7 background fetch

Tags: objective-c, background, ios7, fetch

I am developing a app that use the background fetch.

I would need that the function it execute in background each 5sec, but with the code that I saw in google, the SO decide when the function should to be call.

I would want the this function it execute each 5sec.

The my code is here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this. iOS is responsible to decide when it's best to give your app a chance to fetch content:

> At appropriate times, the system gives background execution time to the apps that support this background mode, launching the app directly into the background if needed.

(From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20))